# Xpath code to fetch value from specific line

Tags: xpath

I am trying to fetch a value from an XML. The XML contains many rows. However, I need to fetch the value from a specific row which changes in position from one XML to another.

I need to fetch value from the row that contains `<FL val="Job Opening Status">`. In this case the value is "Search".

```
<JobOpenings>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="JOBOPENINGID">384474000005082052</FL>
                <FL val="Job Opening ID">
                    <![CDATA[J9298]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">384474000003450003</FL>
                <FL val="Account Manager">
                    <![CDATA[xsxsxs]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Job Type">
                    <![CDATA[Permanent]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Is Hot Job Opening">
                    <![CDATA[false]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Publish">
                    <![CDATA[false]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="No of Candidates Associated">
                    <![CDATA[2]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Posting Title">
                    <![CDATA[Projekteinkäufer]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Last Activity Time">
                    <![CDATA[2019-06-18 10:15:14]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Job Opening Status">
                    <![CDATA[Search]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Date Opened">
                    <![CDATA[2019-06-18]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="CLIENTID">384474000000417148</FL>
                <FL val="Client Name">
                    <![CDATA[xsxsxxxxssss]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="CONTACTID">384474000005082043</FL>
                <FL val="Contact Name">
                    <![CDATA[xsxsxxxxxssssssxxxxx]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="RECRUITERID">384474000003450003</FL>
                <FL val="Assigned Recruiter">
                    <![CDATA[xsxsxsxsxssx]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `xpath` for search element.Try below xpath.

```
//JobOpenings//row//FL[@val='Job Opening Status']
```

**DEMO:**

[image]

```
//JobOpenings//row//FL[@val='Job Opening Status'][contains(.,'Search')]
```

**DEMO 2:**

[image]

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for! thank you so much KunduK

Comment: Is it maybe also possible to define a value here? In this case "Search".

Comment: Check with that tool xpather.com

Comment: Yeah got it. Finding them is working fine with that code. I need to define that this is only fetching those "Job Opening Status" where it is "Seach". Is aht possible anyways? If this is true, I'm gonna fetch those rows.

Comment: `//JobOpenings//row//FL[contains(.,'Search')]`

Comment: OR `//JobOpenings//row//FL[@val='Job Opening Status'][contains(.,'Search')]`

Comment: That works perfect! But now it is only fetching this line. Any way to fetch the entire row when this condition is "true"? Thanks

Comment: Or how do I add multiple XPath in so I can define all Lines I need?

Comment: It depends on your `xml` structure.However the above code will work for all records of `FL` tag which having text `search` and `val='Job Opening Status'`

Comment: check this one as well `//FL[@val='Job Opening Status'][contains(.,'Search')]`

Comment: Thank you. I played around and found the solution together with you code. This works exactly for what we are looking for /row[FL[@val='Job Opening Status'] = "Search"]